# ¿Como hacer un incremento y decremento en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy creando inputs dinámicos que al momento de dar clic en agregar campo te salgan los campos de igual forma eliminar esos inputs con JavaScript. Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que si agrego 3 campos me salga una alerta diciendo que ya no se puede agregar mas campos y que al momento de eliminar decremente ese 3 a 2 , etc . Dependiendo cuantos elimines.

Parece ser que mi problema es al decrementar ya que elimino y de 3 reduce a 2 , elimino otra vez y reduce a 0 y si elimino otra vez me reduce hasta -3. ¿Cual es mi problema, me pueden ayudar por favor? Les dejo mi código , en verdad muchas gracias.

ESTE ES MI CODIGO PARA LOS CAMPOS DINAMICOS CON JAVASCRIPT

```
var nextinput = 0;
var count = 0;

function AgregarCampos() {
  nextinput++;
   var content = '<div class="row">' +
 '<div class="col-xs-4">' +

 '<label>MEDICAMENTO </label><select class="form-control" 
 name="medicamento_id" id="medicamento_id" selected><option 
 value="0">SELECCIONA MEDICAMENTO</option><?php  foreach($medicamento as 
 $value): ?><option  value="<?= $value->medicamento_id?>"><?= $value- 
 >medicamento_desc ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<p align="right"">/    STOCK 
 MEDICO</p> <?= $value->stock_medico ?></option><?php endforeach; ?></select> 
 '+
 '</div>' +

  '<div class="col-xs-2">' +
'<label>CANTIDAD</label><input min="1" max="3" name="cantidad_asignada" 
 id="cantidad_asignada" type="number" class="form-control" value=" "/>' +  
 '</div>' +

 '<div class="col-xs-4">' +
  '<label align="center">INDICACIONES</label><input  name="instrucciones" 
  id="instrucciones" type="text" class="form-control"  value="" />'+
'</div>' 

'<div class="col-xs-1">' +
'<button type="button"  class="pd-setting-ed bte "  title="ELIMINAR"><i 
 class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"aria-hidden="true" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
 </button>'+
'</div>' +
```

''
     ESTA ES MI FUNCION DE ABRIR CAMPOS Y PARA REMOVER LOS CAMPOS

```
$("#campos").append(content);
$(".bte").click(function() {
$(this).closest('div.row').remove();

    if(count >= 3) {

    }else{

        count--;
        $btn = $('input[id="mediA"]'); 
         $btn.val("Agregar Medicamentos ("+count+")");


                  }
              });

         }
```

ESTA FUNCIÓN ES PARA INCREMENTAR

```
          $(function(){
          $btn = $('input[id="mediA"]'); 
          $btn.val($btn.val()+' ('+count+')')

          $btn.click(function(){
           $btn.val($btn.val().replace(count,count+1));
            count++;
           if(count==3) {
           swal({
           icon: 'error',
           title: 'Medicamentos asignados',
           text: 'Solamente puedes asignar 3 medicamentos',
           confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
           confirmButtonText: "¡OK!",
               })
              }
            })
          })
```

Comment: La manera de decrementar con `count--;` es correcta, pero faltaría ver en que momento llamas a cada función y tu html... Por favor crea un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).